# Retrieve distance in Solr 3.6

Tags: solr, lucene

On Solr 3.6, I indexed some location fields, when I search for them everything is fine and the results are correct, but I cannot retrieve the distance for each record, I tried the examples here (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#Returning_the_distance) but they only work for Solr 4.0, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is only a Solr 4.0 feature, you will need to wait for Solr 4.0. I believe that it will be released very soon as the release vote for Solr 4.0.0 just passed today. You could use the Beta release of Solr 4.0 for now to test and then update to the release when it becomes available.

**Update 10/12/12** - [Solr 4.0 has been released](http://lucene.apache.org/solr).